# Why am I redirect to signin page while testing App component w/ Jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing my App component by doing the authentication process (i start at landing page then click on button sign in to be redirect to the signin page , fill the email and password field and click to the signin button to access to the first page which is installations page in my case) but after a login successful response from the server, I am redirected to the sign in page and i can't figure out why. Here is the test in question:

```
it( 'Login', async () => {

        render(<App />)
        
        // Check we are on the good location at the begining of the test
        await waitFor(() => expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/'))

        // env variable needed to connect to the account
        const email = process.env.TEST_EMAIL
        const password = process.env.TEST_PASSWORD

        // // signIn button from the landing page
        const signInButton = screen.getByTestId('landing-signin')
        expect(signInButton).toBeInTheDocument()

        // click action of this button
        fireEvent.click(signInButton)

        // check the path
        await waitFor( async () => expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/signin'))

        // check the presence of elements in signin page
        const emailField = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Email address')
        const passwordField = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Your password')
        
        expect(passwordField).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(emailField).toBeInTheDocument()

        // fill the credentials
        userEvent.type(emailField, email)
        userEvent.type(passwordField, password)

        const button = screen.getByTestId('submit-button')
        expect(button).toBeInTheDocument()

        // fire event login by clicking the button
        act(() => {
            userEvent.click(button)
        })


        // // check the path
        await waitFor( async () => expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/installations'))


        // check the title of installation page to be in the document
        const title = screen.getByText('Installation selection')

        expect(title).toBeInTheDocument()


        // check info to be in the document
        const infoText = screen.getByText('Please, wait a little bit while we are fetching {{data}}')
        expect(infoText).toBeInTheDocument()

        
        // back to /signin
        console.log('window.location.pathname', window.location.pathname)

    })
```

I have jsdom enable, I am using Jest and React-testing-library. I find some elements of installation page but I get redirect to the sign in page.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the `App` component code. Could you please provide the code for the component under test?